# WinForms Toolbox shows not existing controls?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, toolbox

I pressed the right mouse button and selected the **"Show All"** option.

After that, a lot of duplicates of the same controls appeared. However, there are controls that I have not seen before. The problem is that they are disabled, I can't put them on the form.

[image]

I tried to find them in the list by right clicking and selecting **"Choose Items..."**, but they are not in any of the tabs.

How can I find and enable these controls?

Comment: `Show all` shows all Components available (all Platforms). You don't need that. Make sure you have a Form opened in the Designer to see the Controls / Components available in a Windows Forms Project. -- Did you create a new Windows Forms Project in a Solution, or is it something else? What Template did you choose?

Comment: @Jimi 
Windows Forms App (.NET Framework).

Then to what platform are these controls applicable? And how do I find out the specific platform for a specific controller?

Comment: You don't need to *find* anything. If you have a Windows Forms Project and you have a Form in the Designer, the ToolBox shows all Controls available to this Platform. You should have a Group named `All Windows Forms`, plus other sub-groups. -- Did you build this Project from a Template selected in Visual Studio? Or is this an Empty Project? Did you install all the required tools in the `Desktop & Mobile` workload in the VS installer, especially in the `.Net Desktop Development` section? What language are you using? C#, VB.Net, C++/CLI, other? What .Net version are you targeting?

Comment: I was just curious to know what technologies these controls belong to. I don't remember if I chose any template. Yes, I have the `.NET desktop development` extension installed. I'm using `C#, .NET Framework 4.7.2`. Just started wondering because I originally thought they (controls) could be included in WinForms, but you already told me that they are tied to other platforms. I mean, you sort of already answered the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Show all` will display all controls, for example, the MFC Control you screenshot should be a C++ control:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/controls-mfc?view=msvc-170

You created a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework), you just need to uncheck the `Show all` and all the controls you can use will be displayed in the toolbar.